# Connecting 3 MySQL tables, what am I doing wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 3 tables with the following data in MySQL

**tags** table

```
id  |   groupId  |   name   |
-----------------------------
1   |      1     |   tag1   |
2   |      1     |   tag2   |
3   |      1     |   tag3   |
4   |      1     |   tag4   |
```

*groupId column here is unimportant right now.*

**practice** table

```
id  |      name      |
----------------------
1   |   practice 1   |
2   |   practice 2   |
3   |   practice 3   |
4   |   practice 4   |
```

and a bridge between the two (**practiceTag** table)

```
id  |   practiceId   |   tagId    |
-----------------------------------
1   |       1        |      1     |
2   |       1        |      2     |
3   |       1        |      3     |
4   |       2        |      1     |
```

But when I try to use the query:

```
SELECT practice.name
FROM practice
INNER JOIN practiceTag ON practiceTag.practiceId = practice.id
INNER JOIN tags        ON practiceTag.tagId = tags.id
WHERE (tags.id =  "1"
AND tags.id =  "2"
AND tags.id =  "3")
```

it doesn't return anything. And thats ok, since I know my query is kinda messed up. But thats as closest as I can get to show you, what I would like my query to do.

I've searched the forums and find out that I can use a group_concat. But I just can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Sebastian

Comment: USE **OR in the WHERE** you cant have a field with the value 1 AND 2 AND 3 - only 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: use `WHERE tag.id in (1,2,3)`

Comment: Bernd thanks for the reply, but I'm kinda looking for the way to only show the name of the practice that has all of the tags

Comment: Note that id in the bridge table serves no purpose

Answer (score 0):

You `in` clause  not and

```
SELECT practice.name
FROM practice
INNER JOIN practiceTag ON practiceTag.practiceId = practice.id
INNER JOIN tags        ON practiceTag.tagId = tags.id
WHERE  tags.id  in ( '1', '2', '3') ;
```

if the id is numeric

```
SELECT practice.name
FROM practice
INNER JOIN practiceTag ON practiceTag.practiceId = practice.id
INNER JOIN tags        ON practiceTag.tagId = tags.id
WHERE  tags.id  in ( 1, 2, 3) ;
```

the query is equivalent

```
SELECT distinct practice.name
FROM practice
INNER JOIN practiceTag ON practiceTag.practiceId = practice.id
INNER JOIN tags        ON practiceTag.tagId in (1,2,3)
```

And if you want only the practice.name when all the 3 tagsId match the you should use temp table for getting the join table

```
    SELECT distinct practice.name
    FROM practice
    inner join (
        select practiceId from
        ( select distinct  practiceTag.practiceId as praticeId, practiceTag.tagId as tagId
         from tags  ) as t1
        where  tagId in (1,2,3)
        having count(*) > 2
        group by praticeId ) as t2;
```

Comment: in clause is like OR right? And yea, my query still return 0 result. 
I'm kinda looking it would return "practice 1" since that practice has all 3 of the tags.
Thanks

Comment: Id is numeric or string  ? I ahve update the answer for numeric value

Comment: its numeric but even if I do '1' or 1 its the same result

Comment: I have added a new suggestion with a simplyfied query

Comment: it returns a bunch of results, practice1 practice1 practice1 practice2, and it starts all over again. I used DISTINCT but it still shows practice2 which it shouldn't, because im looking for practice with all 3 of the tags.
If i'd use ..tagId in (1), it should return practice1 and 2, since they both have that tag. but when i'd use ...tagId in (1,2), it should only return practice1.

Any idea?

Comment: Related to the data you provided pratice2 don't should appear check for you real data ... and yes need distinct

Comment: I edited the "practiceTag" table above, because I kinda messed it up a bit. Now its the same.

Comment: well but looking to you data .. in praticeTags you have tagsid = 1 also related with practiceid= 2 then you must obtain the result also for pratice2 .. is correct ..

Comment: correct, but since I have tagsId = 2 and 3 only related to practice1. It should only return practice 1 right? since practice2 has only iagId = 1

Comment: This last aspect was not clear for me  .. so you want select the pratice.name only if all the 3 tags match ..... right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112589/discussion-between-sebastjan-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have update the asnwer for this last aspect .. hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

I think your tags.id column is integer not string, so your sql query would be like this:

```
SELECT practice.name
FROM practice
INNER JOIN practiceTag ON practiceTag.practiceId = practice.id
INNER JOIN tags        ON practiceTag.tagId = tags.id
WHERE tags.id in (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `WHERE` part you ask for results that have `id` 1, 2 and 3 at the same time.

Replace the `AND` in your `WHERE` with `OR`